# Making a post request in python for scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

My goal is to be able to access the data from a website after inputting information in a field and hitting submit. I'm using Httpfox to grab which values are needed to "post". I included a screenshot of that below the code.

```
#SECTION 1: import modules
import requests

#SECTION 2: setup variables

url = 'http://www.clarkcountynv.gov/Depts/assessor/Pages/PropertyRecords.aspx?H=redrock&P=assrrealprop/pcl.aspx'

ses = requests.session()

values = []

values.append({
    '__LASTFOCUS' : '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
    '__EVENTTARGET' : 'Submit1',
    '__VIEWSTATE' : '/wEPDwUJLTcyMjI2NjUwZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAgUKY2hrQ3VycmVudAUKY2hrSGlzdG9yeUfXtwoelaE/eJmc1s9mHzvIqqwk',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' : '5889EE07',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : '/wEWBQLnuv+BDALRqf+zDQK+zcmQBAK+zeWoCALVo8avDjkJwx8mhBoXL3mYGKBSY5lYBPxY',
    'hdnInstance' : 'pcl',
    'parcel' : '124-32-816-087', #this is what changes
    'age' : 'pcl17',
    'Submit1' : 'Submit'})

#SECTION 3: grab html text       
r = ses.post(url, data = values)
r.content() #this either throws an error 'too many values to unpack' or gives me the content of the main page if i play around with the input values a little, not the redirected page which is my problem
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to embark in a POST request when you can get the same result with a simple GET

A page inspection of the final page higlights there is an iframe used to show the actual search result.

You can get the result straight from this URL, by replacing "your-parcel-number-here" with the desired value (In your example it was `124-32-816-087`).

> http://sandgate.co.clark.nv.us/assrrealprop/ParcelDetail.aspx?hdnParcel=your-parcel-number-here

Looks like no cookie is needed and hotlinking works (I tried that link in firefox private mode).

Comment: Thanks! This will be enough for what I'm doing. I'll give you the check mark in an hour but I'd also like to be able to post for future purposes ;)

Comment: Regarding the 302 looks like the response is empty, so you should get the redirected URL (the one in the answer above) from the Location header of the response, not from the non-existent HTML.